# Ansible inventory patterns and limit argument

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have the following inventory file called `hosts-local`:

```
host-1   ansible_host=minio-1.localdomain
host-2   ansible_host=minio-2.localdomain
host-3   ansible_host=minio-3.localdomain
host-4   ansible_host=minio-4.localdomain

[minio_cluster_members]
host-1
host-2
host-3
host-4

[nginx_reverse_proxies]
host-1
host-3

[all:vars]
ansible_connection=ssh
```

and a playbook that references the groups:

```
- name: "Install and configure Minio"
  hosts: minio_cluster_members
  become: yes
  remote_user: ansible
  roles:
    - minio

- name: "Install and configure nginx reverse proxy"
  hosts: nginx_reverse_proxies
  become: yes
  remote_user: ansible
  roles:
    - nginx
```

And I invoke ansible like this `$ ansible-playbook -i hosts-local playbook.yml`

My original thought was that I'd have `hosts-local`, `hosts-test` and `hosts-prod` files so that `host-1`, `host-2` etc could be defined on a deployment environment basis (albeit with the duplication of the rest of the groups).

But then someone suggested I look at ansible patterns and specifically the `--limit` argument, referencing [the ansible docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html#common-patterns). This looks particularly relevant:

> Finally, you can use --limit to read the list of hosts from a file by prefixing the file name with @:
>
> ansible-playbook site.yml --limit @retry_hosts.txt

The way I've read this is that I'd have a single inventory file like this:

```
[minio_cluster_members]
host-1
host-2
host-3
host-4

[nginx_reverse_proxies]
host-1
host-3

[all:vars]
ansible_connection=ssh
```

and then a series of files that define `host-1`, `host-2` etc for each environment:

```
# local dev hosts
host-1   ansible_host=minio-1.localdomain
host-2   ansible_host=minio-2.localdomain
host-3   ansible_host=minio-3.localdomain
host-4   ansible_host=minio-4.localdomain
```

```
# test hosts
host-1   ansible_host=test-minio-1.test.domain.com
host-2   ansible_host=test-minio-2.test.domain.com
host-3   ansible_host=test-minio-3.test.domain.com
host-4   ansible_host=test-minio-4.test.domain.com
```

etc.
And then I'd invoke ansible like this: `$ ansible-playbook -i inventory playbook.yml --limit 'all:@hosts-local'`

But for the life of me I cannot get this working. It complains about every line in the limit file (including the comment):

```
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: # local dev hosts
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: host-1   ansible_host=minio-1.localdomain
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: host-2   ansible_host=minio-2.localdomain
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: host-3   ansible_host=minio-3.localdomain
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: host-4   ansible_host=minio-4.localdomain
```

What I am doing wrong? Have I misunderstood how patterns and specifically the `--limit` argument with a file work? What format/syntax should the file be? I cannot find any examples of this on the internet anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the `--limit` argument was a red herring, and not what I wanted in order to solve the problem.
What I've discovered is that you can specify multiple inventory files. So I have the main inventory `hosts`:

```
[minio_cluster_members]
host-1
host-2
host-3
host-4

[nginx_reverse_proxies]
host-1
host-3

[all:vars]
ansible_connection=ssh
```

I have an inventory for local hosts called `hosts-local`:

```
[local]
host-1   ansible_host=minio-1.localdomain
host-2   ansible_host=minio-2.localdomain
host-3   ansible_host=minio-3.localdomain
host-4   ansible_host=minio-4.localdomain
```

and one for test called `hosts-test`:

```
[test]
host-1   ansible_host=test-minio-1.test.domain.com
host-2   ansible_host=test-minio-2.test.domain.com
host-3   ansible_host=test-minio-3.test.domain.com
host-4   ansible_host=test-minio-4.test.domain.com
```

And I can combine them with: `$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i hosts -i hosts-local`

That's it! That's all there is to it.
Plus I get the added benefit of having groups `test`, `local` etc, so I can set variables based on the group name.

Comment: May I ask, why you use `host-1` instead of the real hostname? Is there a use case? Because otherwise I would avoid using "dummy names", as it at least makes your inventory easier to read. Also I think you might run into problems with the duplicate  host names but I am not sure on that one.

Comment: I'm using `host-1` etc rather than the real hostnames because the hostnames are different per environment. On my development machine my VMs are called `minio-1.localdomain` etc. My colleagues might have different hostnames for their development VMs. Our test and prod environments also have different hostnames. So it was about having a single inventory that works across different environments.

Comment: Ah okay, that I get. Then I think your solution is rather fine.